# NetBeans IDE - Build 201202240400 - Why it gets freez without any cause and never get refreshed, unless i kill it

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

How do i now get this window refreshed? This is happening very often now with 201202xxxx build release. Not with the old version.

The IDE completely getting freezes and i have no way to get it refreshed unless i kill and lose my source code.

Is there any better way to get it resolved? (everyday at-least 2/3 times it occurs).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a development build of netbeans. It is quite possible that bugs have been introduced in development builds, but not fixed. I would suggest using the most recent stable release, which is 7.1.